# visualise filters in keras cnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
def build_model(network):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(6, (5,5), padding='valid', activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
    print(np.asarray(model.get_weights())[0].shape)
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5,5), padding='valid', activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(120, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    model.add(Dense(84, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

This is the model in Keras. I want to visualise the filter in the first conv layer. I want to plot the filters themselves, and not the pattern that emerges when we backpropagate gradients all the way to the image.

I found a way to get the weights - using `model.get_weights()`

How can I plot this weights? The shape of `np.asarray(model.get_weights())[0]` is (5,5,3,6).

How can I make six filters of dimension 5x5x3 with it?

Comment: how are u planning on visualizing a 3 dimensional array?

Comment: maybe matplotlib ?

Comment: so what is it you are struggling with?

Comment: The shape looks a bit different. (5,5,3,6). I don't know how can I process that.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe if it would've been (6,5,5,3) then I could just stitch the images together.

Answer (score 0):

Using matplotlib you can plot slices.

You should separate the slices yourself, such as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#normalize these filters first, otherwise they won't be in a suitable range for plotting:

maxVal = filters.max()
minVal = filters.min()
absMax = max(abs(minVal),abs(maxVal))

filters = (filters / absMax)*255


for outputChannel in range(6):
    for inputChannel in range(3):
        filt = filters[:,:,inputChannel,outputChannel]

      #a trick to see negatives as blue and positives as red
        imageRed = np.array(filt)
        imageBlue = np.array(filt)
        imageRed[imageRed<0] = 0
        imageBlue[imageBlue>0]= 0

        print(imageRed)
        print(imageBlue)

        finalImage = np.zeros((filt.shape[0],filt.shape[1],3))
        finalImage[:,:,0] = imageRed
        finalImage[:,:,2] = -imageBlue

        #plot image here
        plt.figure()  
        plt.imshow(finalImage)
```

Comment: `filt = filters[:,:,inputChannel,outputChannel]` I am guessing outputChannel should be outputFilter ?

Comment: And getting this error: 
`filters = int((filters / absMax) * 255)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Certainly :), sorry.

Comment: Just removed the "int" part. Maybe you will need `finalImage.astype(np.uint8)` for plotting.

Comment: There was also a wrong sign in `imageBlue` that I corrected.

Comment: Ok, I get the plot. But according to the conv layer, I should've got 6 filters. I only get one 5x5x3.

Comment: You said in your question that the shape was (5,5,3,6), so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I added the line `plt.figure()`, in case you meant that only one image was appearing.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. With six filters and filter size of (5,5), the model.get_weights()[0] gives the shape as (5,5,3,6). AFAIK, it should've been (6, 5, 5, 3).

Comment: No, it's always (5,5,3,6). 5x5 pixels, 3 input channels, 6 output channels.

Comment: And if I want this code to return a shape of (6, 5, 5, 3) - what would I have to do?

Comment: Check the functions `np.rollaxis`, `np.swapaxis`, `K.permute_dimensions`, etc.

Comment: I meant in your answer, if I need the finalImage as (6,5,5,3) ?